# Fedora 32 on a Dell Latitude E5420 shows Braodcom BCM43228 Wi-Fi but OS can’t find the adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, fedora, wifi-driver

I installed Fedora 32 on my Dell Latitude E5420. The network controller is: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n

But couldn’t start the Wi-Fi as it shows no Wi-Fi adapter found. I tried several methods but I couldn’t solve.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Have you looked at the advice shown here? https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/fedora-linux-install-broadcom-wl-sta-wireless-driver-for-bcm43228/

Comment: I know this may be a silly question, but is the hardware switch for WiFi turned off?